# c++: confusion on const reference used in a nested FOR range usage

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having confusion on the below. So let me explain simply.

```
int ia [3][4] =  {
                     {0, 1, 2, 3},
                     {4, 5, 6, 7},  
                     {8, 9, 10, 11}  
                 };

for (const int (&r)[4] : ia)
      for (int &x : r) --> this has error
             x = 1;
```

The error is "binding value of type 'const int' to reference to type 'int' drops 'const' qualifier".

The reference r to array of int but it's a const reference. That is understandable. The inner for loop using r, it will iterates over the inner array. The r is a const reference to the array but not each item. So why is there error?

I can replace with the below code and it works ..

```
 for (const int (&r)[4] : ia)
            for (int x : r) --> this has error
                      x = 1;
```

This i understand.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cant declare non-const reference to const. It would break `const` rules because you would be able to change value of that constant

Comment: "The reference r to array of int but it's a const reference." All references cannot be rebound, thus all references "are const", so you don't actually write `const` for them. If you add `const`, that means something else entirely.

Comment: why having an int x:r works and int &x:r doesn't?

Comment: We have already written it 3 times, read answers please

Answer (score 3):

You can't take a non-`const` reference to an element of a `const` array. `r` is a reference to a `const` array so you cannot take a non-`const` reference to it's elements.

Try `for(int (&r)[4]: ia)`

Comment: The const reference is what r can do. The array ia is not const. So the iteration of each item is not what const reference can do. Then why having an int works?

Comment: @yapkm01 Even if the referred object is not const, you cannot use a `const` reference to modify it. `const` pointers and references cannot be used to modify the referred object, regardless of rather or not that object is `const` or not. That is what makes them `const`. Having `int x` works because you are no longer taking a reference. It's a copy and you can modify that copy all you want.

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
for (const int (&r)[4] : ia)
```

you have now have an array to `const` `int`'s.  You can't bind a non `const` reference to one of those elements as that violates cont-correctness.

On the other hand when you use

```
for (int x : r)
```

You no longer are taking a reference and instead making a copy.  You can always copy a `const` element into a non `const` element as you can't modify the `const` element from the copy.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear where you are confused; here is a set of possible points of confusion.

- A reference to a const array is the same as a reference to an array over const elements.
- When a C++ programmer says const reference, they mean a reference to const; there is no such thing as a const reference other than a reference to const.
- You cannot get a non-const element reference from a const reference to an array.
- Your code tries to do that.  The compiler says "no".

Answer (score 0):

The array and the ranged based loop just obfuscates the problem. A much simpler code that exhibits the same error is this:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    const int& y = x;
    int& z = y;

}
```

leads to:

```
error: binding value of type 'const int' to reference to type 'int' drops 'const' qualifier
    int& z = y;
         ^   ~
```

Even though `x` is not `const` and using a reference is like using the original variable (most of the time) you cannot obtain a non-const reference from a const reference.

It is also rather easy to understand why this cannot be allowed. Consider

```
void foo(const int& x);
```

`foo` cannot change the value of the parameter passed, but if the above would be allowed, `foo` could be implemented as this:

```
void foo(const int& x) {
    int& y = x;        // now I am allowed to change it
    y++;
}
```

This would obvioulsy break constness, hence it cannot be allowed.